# Routing to an external ip

Tags: routing, tcpip

I have a bunch of equipment (RTUs) that connect to a server to download data using a fixed ip and port.  Due to change of ISP provider I need to change the ip of the server that handles these RTUs to another ip.  The problem is I can't change the configuration of the RTU (they are old equipment and changing the ip address they connect to means changing the firmware).  So, what I thought I could do is to have a router that when a request comes to the fixed ip address and specific port will redirect that to the new ip address of the server.  Can I do that with a router without using a computer to redirect the packets?
Thanks!
Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

You have to NAT the traffic to the proper address, by any means available.
Most firewalls have NAT capability, and some routers do as well.

What device you use really isn't important, as long as it can perform NAT.

Comment: Thanks adaptr.  If I understand right NAT can route to internal IPs, can I route to external IPs as well using NAT?  Because the new server is external to my network.